# populate label with control id

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="audition_ID" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource10" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="audition_ID" HeaderText="audition_ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="audition_ID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="audition_date" HeaderText="audition_date" SortExpression="audition_date" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ins_ID" HeaderText="ins_ID" SortExpression="ins_ID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="insturment_name" HeaderText="insturment_name" SortExpression="insturment_name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="audition_status" HeaderText="audition_status" SortExpression="audition_status" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="audition_location" HeaderText="audition_location" SortExpression="audition_location" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="audition_time" HeaderText="audition_time" SortExpression="audition_time" />
                        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="audition_ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="judgescores.aspx?auditionID={0}" HeaderText="Details" Text="Details" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

I am using a grid view to display information for a database based on the selection in a drop down list. I have that working and when selecting the DDL- the grid view updates and shows the associated records.

I then added a "Details" hyperlink column that directs to the details.aspx page and picks up the ID so it shows the correct details associated with that record.

```
DataNavigateURLFormat = details.aspx?ID={0}
```

I can see the ID in the URL od this details page. What I am trying to do now is take that ID and populate it in a label on the details page.

I am exploring the "Expression" property in the Data section of the label properties- but have not found any luck using "AccessControlID" or "ClientIDMode" giving it a "RouteValue".

I was also exploring going in the code of the details page (details.aspx.vb)

and doing something like

```
lbldetail.Text = @ID
```

But not sure if that would work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Contents of judgescores.aspx.vb page...

```
Partial Class Judges_judgescores
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Sub Page_Load()

   lblCurrentAudition.Text = Request.QueryString[audition_ID]
End Sub
```

Comment: I think that what you want to do is `lbldetail.Text  = Request.QueryString["id"]`

Comment: I put it in Page_Load Sub and that worked.

Comment: I put it in Page_Load Sub and that worked.

However, the label is still empty when the page loads

Comment: It'd be great if you can share with use your GridView markup

Comment: It's too long to enter a comment here - how would I upload it?

Here is the last bit.. the variable i'm trying to capture and display in the label is "Audition ID" - I can see it clearly in the URL for the Details page. I just can't figure out how to grab it..

DataNavigateUrlFields="audition_ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="judgescores.aspx?auditionID={0}" HeaderText="Details" Text="Details" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>

Comment: Edit your question

Comment: So according to your markup you should use `Request.QueryString["auditionID"]`

Comment: I'm getting 2 errors when doing just that

BC30311 Value of type 'NameValueCollection' cannot be converted to 'String'.
BC30205 End of statement expected. Band Application1


I have added the entire contents of my judgescores.aspx.vb file to the questions.

Thanks for all your help btw! It is SERIOUSLY appreciated

Comment: Sorry in VB.NET it should be `Request.QueryString("auditionID")`

Comment: Thanks! Updated that and got no erros- but still not able to get it to display.

The exact code I used is "lblauditionID.Text = Request.QueryString("audition_ID")


The label on the details page is named correctly in the properties of the label as well as it's reference in the details.aspx.vb page

Comment: "audition_ID" or "auditionID"?

Comment: Ahh, I see I used both in the HyperLink field

HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="audition_ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="judgescores.aspx?auditionID={0}"

I updated the DataNavigateURLFormatString to audition_ID but still no luck.

I also tried keeping the FormatString as auditionID and updatating my judgescores.aspx.vb to Request.QueryString(auditionID) and it is the same result.
In the DB and data sets it is "audition_ID"